# Find out if GL_TEXTURE_2D is active in shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I would like to know if GL_TEXTURE_2D is active in the shader.

I am binding a color to the shader as well as the active texture (if GL_TEXTURE_2D is set) and need to combine these two.

So if texture is bound, mix the color and the texture (sampler2D * color) and if no texture is bound, use color.

Or should I go another way about this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is not quite clear what you mean by 'GL_TEXTURE_2D is active' or 'GL_TEXTURE_2D is set'.

Please note the following:

- `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` has no effect on your (fragment) shader. It parametrizes the fixed function part of your pipeline that you just replaced by using a fragment shader.
- There is no 'direct'/'clean' way of telling from inside the GLSL shader whether there is a valid texture bound to the texture unit associated with your texture sampler (to my knowledge).
- Starting with GLSL 1.3 you might have luck using `textureSize(sampler, 0).x > 0` to detect the presence of a valid texture associated with *sampler*, but that might result in undefined behavior.
- The [ARB_texture_query_levels](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_query_levels.txt) extension does indeed explicitly state that `textureQueryLevels(gsampler2D sampler)` returns 0 if there is no texture associated with *sampler*.

Should you go another way about this? I think so: Instead of making a decision inside the shader, simply bind a 1x1 pixel texture of 'white' and unconditionally sample that texture and multiply the result with *color*, which will obviously return `1.0 * color`. That is going to be more portable and faster, too.

Comment: +1 for the white texture method. The only solution listed elsewhere is to use two different shaders, which is pointless in most cases.

Comment: opengl by default assigns a value to your shader sampler, so in order to work you need to check if textureSize is greater than 1